# Is there a way to work with microsoft LUIS with React Native?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, azure-language-understanding, voice-recording

Is there a way to work with Microsoft LUIS with React Native ? I want to record the voice using microphone, store it in a wave file and send that wave file to LUIS to recognize the intent ?
Any suggestions,Any examples ?

Comment: make us of API's provided bu LUIS

Comment: okay,but i dont see any react native support for LUIS

Comment: There is No SDK as such, But you can do it youself by using REST API's provided by LUIS, I have done it in Android Java Native, It should be possible in React too

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions to handle this

**1. Using Voice to text conversion from Android and LUIS**

This one is fairly simple, You can convert Audio to Text https://stackoverflow.com/a/51954228/2850044 and then using the text you can have a call to LUIS Endpoint as shown in the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/LUIS/luis-get-started-get-intent-from-rest?pivots=programming-language-nodejs)

**2. Using Bing Speech and LUIS**

This one is using Bing Speech API and LUIS using this [link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/luis-speech-api-integration/)